# Comparing files image that look The same but are completely different images

Tags: python, image

I have 2 folders, one (Folder A) contains images from a word document extracted using Save As Filtered Web Page, the other one (Folder B) is extracted by converting the document to a .zip file. Folder B has high quality images but is missing an image (Canvas Object was not extracted), Folder A has low quality images but has the missing image from Folder B. Images in both folders are visually the same, but programmatically not (different sizes, names, and quality), How can I programmatically find the missing image, I cannot think of any way to do that, and I could not find any method online to do that.

Comment: Have you tried using [image hashing](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/), and looking for the image hash within B which has the highest distance away from all image hashes in A?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914673/measuring-similarity-between-two-rgb-images-in-python and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images

Comment: @NickODell I am looking into it right now but how would i look for hash in B that furthest distance from all in A? is there a fast way to do that? I have the images in each folder in a hashtable

Comment: @ahmad Comparing image hashes this way is very fast. You could likely just use brute force. Compare every hash in B to every hash in A. That's probably fast enough. How many images do you have?

Comment: @NickODell for the base case i have right now its 10 but i looked at other documents which i would have to do this to it is probably around 50, my train of thought was like you said and have a list for every hash in B with with distances to every has in A, so list of lists, then somehow return the value of the list of which each value is greater than each value in every other list but that sounds like a really bad code, another thing i did was get the average distance but that gave me a wrong answer i think because some images are black and white and some a colored

Comment: 50 images is 50*50=2500 comparisons, which is not that many. You can break this up into two steps: 1) In your list of lists, for each list, replace the list with the minimum of that list. 2) Get the argmax (the index of the maximum value) of that list. That is the index of the image in B which is furthest away from any image in A.

Comment: @NickODell i'll try this and report back

Comment: @NickODell Thank you it worked, i had to change some images from png with transparent bg to jpg with a white one, but I noticed something 2 images gave very close values to each other one gave 12 (missing one) and one gave 10, would this be a problem in the future?

Comment: @ahmad It's hard to say. It could be that you have two images in your document which are very similar. Could be that image hashing is falsely saying that two images are close when they aren't, which can happen. Two ideas for how to deal with it, if it's the second one: 1) use image hashing to identify a list of candidates, and then use some more expensive but more accurate image comparison to pick the most different one. 2) Output the top 3 images rather than the top image, and let the user pick.

Comment: @NickODell i dont want the user to do anything i want it be fully automated because i am migrating alot  of word documents to confluence. I also noticed that the some pictures has very different sizes one is very large one is very small so tomorrow i will try to make both images the same size (resize the big one) then compare maybe i'll get a better result